# How to define cluster keys with start and end timestamps?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

There's event data with start timestamp and end timestamp. The data is huge so I'm planning to create cluster keys to increase query performance. I guess date column would be a good candidate for cluster key.

However, I'm confused with which timestamp column should I convert to date and use for clustering; because choosing the timestamp can depend on the question asked. How would I create cluster this table?

Comment: Please consult with your Sales Engineer. Selecting a good clustering key for a large table is easier when you've done it 100 times than when it's the first time. If the Sales Engineer needs help, he/she has internal resources to call on for help. (I've seen the effects of bad key selection, and am open to these discussions to prevent that.)

Answer (score 3):

All clustering does is re-order your files (it also actually combines partitions if you have many small partitions). Just like dis-defragmentation tools used to do for hard drives. And just like for harddrives, files/data that is together, is faster. But here what you are really trying to do is not load data. Thus if you have data across years, and you have a `WHERE start_time > '2020-08-12'::date` you want to not touch most of those partition, thus save a lot of IO

You should thus "order it"/"cluster on" keys that you use the most in your queries. If you events end roughly within the same day as they start, start or end makes sense, but I would guess you would pick start, and truncate that to date in the cluster key definition.

The [Strategies for Selecting Clustering Keys](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-clustering-keys.html#strategies-for-selecting-clustering-keys) are quite to the point.

As for how to do it, if it exists already, you want the [ALTER commands](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-clustering-keys.html#changing-the-clustering-key-for-a-table)

Comment: Worth noting the clustering doesn't come for free, however performance increases more commonly found in other parts of the SQL especially if you focus on the I/O.

Comment: yes, the credits used to rewrite those partitions can and do add up. And if the table has high churn, the clustering writes run a lower priority than normal writes, which means it backs off, but it still "spent time", (aka it costs more than it could). Like many things, manually rewriting the table can often be faster, and cheaper than cluster, but takes effort to setup.